# View REST API results in Microsoft Edge

Tags: xml, rest, microsoft-edge

When debugging a REST API, it's helpful to paste your API call into a browser and see the XML. With IE 11, the output may show all the tags run together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://xxx"><xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Where you want to see it as nicely formatted XML. With IE 11, it was easy to just change a setting in Internet Options:

- Click the "Content" tab.
- Under "Feeds and Web Slices", click "Settings".
- Under "Feeds and Web Slice Settings", check "Turn on feed reading view".
- Click OK, click OK.

But Microsoft Edge doesn't use Internet Options. Where is a similar setting for Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 0):

According [this article](https://pmhelpdesk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034114693-Unable-to-read-RSS-feeds-with-Google-Chrome-Firefox-or-Edge), you can know that most web browsers stopped supporting RSS feeds natively.And this is now the default behavior and there is nothing you can do. There are no settings to adjust to enable RSS feeds. Your browser simply doesn't support it any longer.

If you really need to view it in Edge, you have to download an appropriate RSS Feed reader extension/add-on for your Edge.

Comment: Actually, my question has nothing to do with RSS feeds. As I stated, I use my browser to test REST API results, which are returned as XML. This is about reading XML as well-formatted XML in a browser.

Comment: When you respond to the correct xml document, Edge should be able to display the response data in a good format, like this: [resut image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C35w.png). So I am not sure if there may be any problems in your code. And for testing Rest api, you can also use related tools, such as [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).